# Watch for Dynamically Added Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

Is there a listener where I can watch and run code if a class is dynamically added to an element? I'm on a WordPress CMS and a plugin I'm using us adding a class dynamically, I want to catch on when that happens and run some custom code.

change / onChange doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#test').change(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Is there another listener I can add that will catch this?

I didn't think it mattered at first, but the dynamic class(es) are being added after an ajax call. I'm currently trying to work with `ajaxComplete()` but not having any luck.

Comment: Event delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Howdy_McGee i deleted my answer just because that does not answer your question in a way i got it.

Comment: @Jai Thanks though, you're answer was definitely helpful. I was able to use `.ajaxComplete()` - split the classes (which your answer had) and see if the certain dynamic class was added. I'll post my code in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use `ajaxComplete()` to find the dynamic class being added via ajax.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
    if ($('#test').hasClass('invalid')){...}
}
```

To anybody interested - I'm using Contact Form 7 with WordPress and using the above code to run custom jquery if my WPCF7 form is invalid.

Comment: FYI You can just do `$('#test').hasClass('invalid')`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var target = $("#test").get(0);

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    // do stuff when
    // `attributes` modified
    // i.e.g., 
    alert(mutation.type);
    target.innerHTML = "class added: " 
                       + "<em>" 
                       + target.className 
                       + "</em>";
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

    $("#test").addClass("test-1");

    // later, you can stop observing
    // observer.disconnect();

})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/35cVL/

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is modify the plugin and fire a custom event when the class is added. There are no events to listen for element attribute changes, and the reason is that these changes are always code induced so the W3 assumes custom implementation of any events needed.

If the plugin's source code is not available, your only option is to build something yourself.