# Listen for a function to be fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

this is more of an academic question than a problem I'm having.

I've written a function that sets up a click handler for Google Analytics Event Tracking. It starts off by removing any previous click handlers using a namespace so as not to interfere with other click handlers that may be applied. Using jQuery's `$.each()` it basically loops through the IDs in an array, applies the `category`,`action` and `label` as `data-*` attributes and a class to reference it by later.

It then uses the `data` attributes set previously to set up a click handler which in turn fires the Google Analytics Event Tracking.

My question is basically, can I bind this function to an `.unbind()` or `.off()` method that targets all click handlers? (not namespaced ones)

So if someone else unbinds *all* click handlers on a button that the Event Tracking code is applied to, the `setupEventHandlers()` function is run  automatically and reapplies the lost GA Event Tracking code?

**UPDATED QUESTION**

My original question might have been unclear in what I was trying to achieve.

So there is a button in the DOM.

```
<input type='submit' value='Confirm' id='confirm-btn'>
```

`setupEventHandlers()` runs as soon as the DOM is ready, and applies an event listener to `#confirm-btn`, which is listening for the `click` event. Another function `randomFunction()` decides that it needs to remove **all** event listeners from `#confirm-btn`, using the `$.off()` method. I would like to be able to allow `randomFunction()` to remove all event listeners, as it may not have a namespace (for reason *x*), and then run `setupEventHandlers()` again once `$.off()` has finished.

Consider that I can't directly edit the HTML because it's used across multiple sites, and the tracking code is for a single instance.

```
function setupEventHandlers(){
    var buttonsToTrack = [['#buttonId','category','action', 'label'],
                          ['#buttonId2','category2','action2', 'label2'],
                          ['#buttonId3','category3','action3', 'label3']]

    $('.js-buttonTracker').off('click.eventTrackingHandler');

    $.each(buttonsToTrack, function(index, buttonDetails){
        if(document.querySelector(buttonDetails[0]) != null){
            $(buttonDetails[0]).attr('data-category', buttonDetails[1]);
            $(buttonDetails[0]).attr('data-action', buttonDetails[2]);
            $(buttonDetails[0]).attr('data-label', buttonDetails[3]);
            $(buttonDetails[0]).addClass('js-buttonTracker');
        }
    });

    $('.js-buttonTracker').on('click.eventTrackingHandler', function(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', $(this).attr('data-category'), $(this).attr('data-action'), $(this).attr('data-label')]);
        console.log($(this).attr('data-category') + ' ' + $(this).attr('data-action'), $(this).attr('data-label'));
    });

}
```

Comment: You can save the old value of `$.fn.off` and redefine it with your own function that does what you want and then calls the saved value.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I could define `.off()` to do what it normally does, and then use `setupEventHandlers()` as a callback?

Comment: See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Save the original .off in a variable
(function(jq_off, recursive) {
    // Redefine .off
    $.fn.off = function(event, selector, function) {
        var save_recursive = recursive;
        recursive = true;
        // Then call the original $.off
        var return_val = jq_off.apply(this, arguments);
        recursive = save_recursive;
        if (!recursive) {
            setupEventHandlers();
        }
        return return_val;
    };
)($.fn.off, false);
```

You don't need to redefine `.unbind`, as it just calls `.off`.

Comment: I think I understand. A self executing function that sets `$.fn.off` again and includes `setupEventHandlers()`, and then includes itself? Where `jq_off` is `$.fn.off`. Would this cause a loop of sorts, as `setupEventHandlers` uses `$.fn.off` from the start?

Comment: @Barmar Can you clarify: is this known as monkey patching? Hence, after these lines are run, does it mean that every line of code after these has $.fn.off redefined? In other words, no turning back?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term before, but yes, this is monkey patching. I noticed a bug -- I wasn't returning the original function's return value. I've fixed that. And yes, once you do this, the `.off` method is redefined for all future calls.

Comment: @Barmar, just so I am clear, would this run the `$.fn.off` first, then `setupEventHandlers()`? Or would I simply have to rearrange the `if(!recursive){}` part to be after `var return_val = jq_off.apply()` ?

Comment: If I understand what you want to do correctly, you call `setupEventHandlers()` in the _Do your work here_ part of the function.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated my question, I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: I've changed my answer to run `setupEventHandlers()` after the regular code, instead of before.

Answer (score 0):

My advise to you is to use `data-` tag elements and assign them a click listener independent of other functionalities, for example :

HTML:

`<a href="http://google.com" data-toggle="GAPush" data-event="_trackEvent" data-action="google"....>..</a>`

JS:

`$('[data-toggle="GAPush"]').click(function() { 
   var eventname = $(this).data('name');
   var action = $(this).data('action');
   //do your login here and read other parameters from data-eventname m use _gapush()
});`

you know you can have unlimited `data-` tag elements if you need them for other functionalities.

Comment: `tag elements` should really be `attributes`. An html tag creates a `dom element`

Comment: Thanks @Antoine but I'm already using `data-` attributes to store information relating to the button. My question was about reapplying a click handler once a different function has accidentally removed the GA click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try (this pattern)

Edit

v2

It should be possible to utilize `setInterval` to "poll" for the event `namespace` being attached, or not , to the target elements

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  $._data($(".js-buttonTracker")[0], "events") != undefined &&
  $._data($(".js-buttonTracker")[0], "events")
  .click[0].namespace === "eventTrackingHandler" 
  ? $.noop() 
  : setupEventHandlers()
}, 1000);
```

v1

html

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<!-- `data`, `em` for `event` status notifications at jsfiddle -->
<data></data>
<em></em>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    setupEventHandlers = function (status) {
        if (status === "on") {
        // if `events` `off`, turn back `on` by calling `_events()`
            _events();
            $(window).trigger("mousemove.check");
        } else {
            $("data").html(status);
        };
    };

    eventsCheck = function () {
        $(window).on("mousemove.check", function (e) {
            // `target` `elements` ; 
            // e.g., `.js-buttonTracker`
            var el = $("button");
            // if `events` attached to `el`,
            // check `events` `namespace`
            if ($._data($(el)[0], "events") != undefined) {
                $.each($._data($(el)[0], "events").click, function (k, v) {
                    if (v.namespace != "eventTrackingHandler") {
                        setupEventHandlers("attach `eventTrackingHandler`"
                                          + " namespace called");
                    } else {
                        $("data").html("`eventTrackingHandler`"
                                      + " namespace attached");
                    };
                });
            } else {
                // if `events` _not_ attached to `el`,
                // turn `events` back `on` by calling
                // `setupEventHandlers("on")` 
                $("data").html("`eventTrackingHandler` namespace `off` ,"
                              + " turning back `on` in 1 seconds");
                // `setTimeout()` utilized here to show operability,
                // alternatively, could call `setupEventHandlers("on")`
                // without delay
                setTimeout(function () {
                    setupEventHandlers("on");
                }, 1000);
            };
        });
    };
    eventsCheck();

    _events = function () {
        $("button").on("click.eventTrackingHandler", function (e) {
            $("em").html("clicked at " + $.now());
            // turn `off` `events` for `button`'s when `button`
            // having `text` of `"3"` `click`ed,
            // simulating the condition 
            // "if someone else unbinds all click handlers on a button
            //  that the Event Tracking code is applied to" ,
            // "observed" by `eventsCheck()` ,
            // which calls `_events()` within `setTimeout()`
            if ($(e.target).text() === "3") {
                $("button").off("click.eventTrackingHandler");
            };
        });
    };
    _events();
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/z5u97/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't using the `mousemove` event costly ?

Comment: @GaryLuck Not certain , without definition of "costly". Utilized `mousemove` as that `event` would , perhaps , notify "catching" removal of `event`(s) at target element relatively quickly. Another option may be `MutationObserver` , see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24069837/2801559 , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver ; which , with some adjustments and testing , could possibly be substituted in for `mousemove`

Comment: Sorry, I meant costly to performance and potentially cause a users browser to slow.

Comment: @GaryLuck Relevant to "cost", try `$._data($("body")[0], "events").mousedown` at `console` , this page . If an `attribute` could added to or removed from the target elements when an `unbind` or `off` occurred , `MutationObserver` could be utilized . However, that would necessitate yet another event handler to ensure addition or removal of attributes when `setupEventHandlers` was adjusted . Or, alternatively , the `MutationObserver` object could be modified to "observe" event attachment or removal . fwiw , `mousemove` event is perhaps utilized at various pages on the www . Try / test it locally