# Jquery for each loop on interval check active state on this element

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am using Drupal Views slideshow, the slides rotate, views slideshow automatically adds a class active when an item is active, I would like to constantly monitor .views-slideshow-pager-field-item items to see if they do at that moment contain the active class, if not I would like to hide the active state image and show the not active state image. Please see my code below, it will make more sense.

It does not work, the active state changes constantly between the two divs, I want to monitor this, to determine if I need to show the active state image or the original.

Thanks in advance.

```js
(function($) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(".views-slideshow-pager-field-item").each(function(){
   if ($(this).is(".views-slideshow-pager-field-item.active")) {
    $(this).find(".pager-item .pager-item-main-state").hide();
    $(this).find(".pager-item .pager-item-active-state").show();
   }else{
    $(this).find(".pager-item .pager-item-main-state").show();
    $(this).find(".pager-item .pager-item-active-state").hide();
   }
  });
 }, 1000);

}(jQuery));
```

```html
//this one is active
<div id="views_slideshow_pager_field_item_bottom_home_page_banner-block_0" class="views-slideshow-pager-field-item views_slideshow_pager_field_item views-row-odd views-row-first active">
    <div class="views-content-field-slide-control-image-active">
        <div class="pager-item">
            <div class="pager-item-main-state"><img src="slide_control_demo.jpg" alt="" height="42" width="42"></div>
            <div class="pager-item-active-state"><img src="slide_control_active_demo.jpg" alt="" height="42" width="42"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//not active
<div id="views_slideshow_pager_field_item_bottom_home_page_banner-block_1" class="views-slideshow-pager-field-item views_slideshow_pager_field_item views-row-even views-row-last"> 
    <div class="views-content-field-slide-control-image-active">
        <div class="pager-item">
            <div class="pager-item-main-state"><img src="slide_control_demo2.jpg" alt="" height="42" width="42"></div>
            <div class="pager-item-active-state"><img src="slide_control_active_demo2.jpg" alt="" height="42" width="42"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should find the script and see if you can add an event to it. I am not family with this drupal setup, but looks like it uses the cycle script. If so, look to see if you can change the 'options' (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), adding a similar function for 'after' would do it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068750/watch-for-dynamically-added-class/

Comment: @fanfavorite - I don't know if it's good practice to edit inside a drupal module (module updates will replace custom code), but I went ahead and followed your advice and it's working now. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the script and see if you can add an event to it in the configuration. I am not family with this drupal setup, but looks like it uses the cycle script. If so, look to see if you can change the '[options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)', adding a similar function for 'after' would do it. You don't want to edit core files though, so if there is no configuration option, you could override the after function with your own custom like:

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults.after = function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
   //Your code here
}
```

Make sure that jQuery and the cycle function are already initialized before you do this.