# More efficient way of listening for jQuery hasClass method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, listener

I'm trying to listen if an element with the id of `dropdown` has the class `open`. If `#dropdown` has `.open`, add class `badge-border` to class `badge`. If `#dropdown` doesn't have `.open`, remove class `badge-border` from class `badge`. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Language (EN)</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Currency ($)</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Account</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"><span class="badge">36</span></i> My Cart</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      var interval = setInterval(changeBadge, 1);

      function changeBadge() {
          if ($('#dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
              console.log('add class border');
              // clearInterval(interval);
              $(".badge").addClass("badge-border");
          } else {
              console.log('remove class border');
              $(".badge").removeClass("badge-border");
          }
      };

  });
```

The above way works to accomplish my goals, but I have a feeling that listening to an event every 1 millisecond isn't the best way to do it.

To make more sense of all this, you can view the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/obliviga/qt7o3u6e/2/

You will need to maximize the viewport until the navbar is not in mobile mode, then click the shopping cart dropdown to see the badge's border added.

**EDIT:**
The reason why I implemented the way I did is because when the user clicks out of the cart dropdown, it should close, and the styles should revert to how they were before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: The reason why I implemented the way I did is because when the
>   user clicks out of the cart dropdown, it should close, and the styles
>   should revert to how they were before.

Updated , Added `click` event attached to `document` which removes `.open` class from `#dropdown` if present , calls handler of `#dropdown a` `click` event with `this` set to `#dropdown a` , with handler remove `.badge-border` class from `.badge` element which should revert styles of `.badge` to properties initially set at `css`.

---

Try attaching `click` event to selector `$("#dropdown a")` , calling `.delay(1)` on `$(this).parents("#dropdown")` within handler , `.queue()` function to check for `open` class , `.toggleClass()` to set `$(this).parents("#dropdown")` class on `$(this).parents("#dropdown")` with second argument `Boolean` `$(this).parents("#dropdown")`

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  function changeBadge(e) {
      $(this).parents("#dropdown")
          .delay(1, "check")
          .queue("check", function () {
          $(".badge").toggleClass("badge-border", $(this).hasClass("open"));
      }).dequeue("check")
  }

  $("#dropdown a").click(changeBadge);
  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
      var elem = $("#dropdown");
      if ($(e.target).is("#dropdown *")) {
          return false
      } else {
          if (elem.is(".open") || $(".badge").hasClass("badge-border")) {
              elem.removeClass("open");
              changeBadge.call(elem.find("a.dropdown-toggle")[0])
          }
      }
  })
  });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qt7o3u6e/6/

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, the reason why I implemented the way I did is because when the user clicks out of the cart dropdown, it should close, and the styles should revert to how they were before. With your solution, when the user clicks outside the dropdown, the white border on the badge persists.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy _"the reason why I implemented the way I did is because when the user clicks out of the cart dropdown, it should close, and the styles should revert to how they were before."_ Can include this detail at Question ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068750/watch-for-dynamically-added-class/

Comment: Apologies. It has been included.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) intended exactly to track DOM changes, including changes of attribute values.

Note that IE supports Mutation Observers since version 11. For IE 10 and older, a fallback is needed.