# Make mutation observer faster and less resource heavy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, mutation-observers

I'm trying to use a mutation observer but I'm finding that it's quite tough to implement without having the browser slow down. Perhaps it's just my implementation but I'd love for someone to take a look and see if there is anything that can be improved.

I'm also trying to check for mutations to the `p` tag but I can't seem to figure it out. Right now I'm checking mutations for `document.body` because I couldn't figure out how to implement `p`.

```
var arrayOfP = $("p").text(); //Get p tags
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {

    tempArrayOfP = $("p").text(); //Get p after mutation
    tempArrayOfP = tempArrayOfP.replace(arrayOfP,''); //Get the difference between before and after mutation (this line doesn't seem to work...
    arrayOfP = $("p").text(); //Store new case of current p tags
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tempArrayOfP, manageResponse); //Send p tags to other file in chrome extension

});
observer.observe(document.body, { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
```

Any ideas? The `tempArrayOfP` replacing doesn't seem to work, and currently my chrome extension is redoing everything on the page when the message is sent.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: `var arrayOfP = $("p").text(); //Get p tags` does not return `p` `DOM` elements , but `text` of `p` elements ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Yes. In the other file of the extension I compare values in my database to the `p` text..

Comment: _"Yes. In the other file of the extension I compare values in my database to the p text.."_ Not how `MutationObserver` processes data ; requires `DOM` element , not `text` . See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068750/watch-for-dynamically-added-class/

Comment: The dom request is being made in the `observer.observe`. Right now it's reacting to `document.body` because I can't seem to get it to react to `p`.

Comment: Can include `html` at Question which has `p` elements ? Is expected result to observe text of all `p` elements ?

Answer (score 0):

The mutations passed to the callback can provide the old and new values, which will spare you from having to traverse the DOM for every mutation.

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var oldValue, newValue;
    if(mutation.type === 'characterData' &&
        mutation.target.parentNode && 
        mutation.target.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'p')
    {
      oldValue = mutation.oldValue;
      newValue = mutation.target.textContent;
    } else if(mutation.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'p' && 
             mutation.addedNodes.length &&
             mutation.removedNodes.length) 
    {
      oldValue = mutation.removedNodes[0].textContent;
      newValue = mutation.addedNodes[0].textContent;
    } else {
      return;
    }
                                        
    // do stuff
    document.write('old: ' + oldValue + ', new: ' + newValue);
  }); 
}); 
  
  observer.observe(document.body, { characterDataOldValue: true, subtree: true, childList: true, characterData: true });

// test
document.querySelector('p').textContent = 'good bye';
```

```html
<p>hello world</p>
```

As for extracting the difference between the old and new text, your method assumes the mutation has not removed any text, or inserted text in between the existing text. If this occurs, the string in replace will not match anything.

Comment: `mutation.target` would be `p` , not `mutation.target.parentNode`

Comment: I got an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null` and a bunch of `MutationRecord` objects in the console...

Comment: @guest271314 not always. When you edit the text via dev-tools inspector, the target is the actual textNode contained in the `p`.

Comment: @levi Hmm, I still seem to get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null`...

Comment: @Katie i forgot to check if a `parent` exists. Updated it. As for new content, that needs to be handled differently, since no old value will exist. I suggest you read up - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elems = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));

var text = elems.map(function(el) {
  return el.textContent
})

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.target.nodeName === "P") {
      var index = elems.indexOf(mutation.target);
      console.log("mutation type:", mutation.type + "\n"
                 , "new text:", mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeValue + "\n"
                 , "old text:", text[index]);
    }
  });
})

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
});

document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].textContent = 123;
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].textContent = 456;
```

```html
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p>
```

Comment: This creates an infinite loop for me, my content is being added to the page about every second and it's very slow... Doesn't seem to take mutations into account?

Comment: @Katie See updated post . _"my content is being added to the page about every second and it's very slow..."_ ? Not certain interpret correctly ? What is expected result of using `MutationObserver` ?

Comment: when new content is dynamically loaded into the page (think facebook, and twitter how they load their content) that a piece of my code is executed... Can that be done?

Comment: @Katie _"when new content is dynamically loaded into the page (think facebook, and twitter "_ Not tried "facebook" , here . _"how they load their content) that a piece of my code is executed... Can that be done?"_ Yes, include function, or _"that a piece of my code"_ within statement `{}` following `if (mutation.target.nodeName === "P")` condition

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've done that, but it executes my code every second and it is making the page extremely slow. Even if no new content is loaded my code is being executed every second. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Katie See at first comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425192/make-mutation-observer-faster-and-less-resource-heavy/32425782?noredirect=1#comment52716885_32425782 above _"my content is being added to the page about every second"_ at previous comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425192/make-mutation-observer-faster-and-less-resource-heavy/32425782?noredirect=1#comment52717356_32425782 _"Even if no new content is loaded my code is being executed every second."_ ? Is content loaded every second , not loaded every second ? Is `MutationObserver` `js` within a `setInterval` block ?