# Solution to async save html page, when updates occur

Tags: javascript, html, browser

the problem sounds simple (looked for it already, but was not able to find anything similar): there is a complex (proprietary) web-page which updates (through JS) some information at random times. I would like to save the actual HTML code (on the client side!) as soon as the HTML page content changed (due to updates on the JS side).
Please note: I am looking for an async implementation (calling wget on that web-page, each x seconds, is not a solution!).

Do you know if there is anything (a tool / web-browser plug-in or add-on / code) which already does this? 
I would however favor an (already implemented) browser plug-in / addon, as the page is quite complex.

Regards,
K.

Comment: Calling wget multiple times would not help, you'd always get the initial state

Comment: Do you have write access to the dynamic content (the updating JS file)?

Comment: @remdevtec: no, I can only get the page and save its HTML.

Comment: Try using `MutationObserver`

Comment: @guest271314: I am not quite familiar with web development, although I could get fast. Is there an add-on based on MutationObserver already available? .. or some clear tutorial how to implement this without weeks of work ;) ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068750/watch-for-dynamically-added-class